# Creating a function for data query using matrix and vectors

Tags: python, matrix, vector, iteration

I am creating a function called pagerank that takes as input the set `edges`, a teleport probability `a` and a positive integer `iters` and computes the transition probability matrix.

the edges being defined as:
`edges =[[0,1], [1,1], [2,0], [2,2], [2,3], [3,3], [3,4], [4,6], [5,5], [6,6], [6,3]]`

It then starts from an arbitrary probability vector (say one full of 1/Ns where N is the number of all states) and then multiplies this vector with the transition probability matrix iters times.

The function should return the resulting vector

Does anyone know how I can create a function to handle the vector multiplication with the vector? if anyone can write me a sample solution about my query, it would help me a lot

Comment: Please, provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What exactly the input is, and what it desired returned value?

Comment: I haven't done this before so I needed guidance. I only know how to declare the function which would be def function(edges, a, iters):

Comment: OK, but still don't understand, what "probability vector" you are saying about? If `iters=2` and `a=3`, what output do you expect?

Comment: so its a random probability value as a vector. probability a teleports the user to any random page with a probability α. so a is assigned a value at random

Comment: The function will essentially take as input the set edges, a teleport probability a and a positive integer iters and computes the transition probability matrix